# How to extract the data from text file if the txt file do not have column?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to save the wimp mass only from the text file below into another txt file for plotting purposes. I have a lot of other .txt files to read WIMP_Mass from. I try to use `np.loadtxt` but cannot since there is string there. Can you guys suggest the code to extract Wimp_Mass, and the output value to be appended to .txt file without deleting the old values.

```
 Omegah^2:    2.1971043635736895E-003
 x_f:    25.000000000000000     
 Wimp_Mass:     100.87269924860568       GeV
 sigmav(xf):    5.5536288606920853E-008
 sigmaN_SI_p:   -1.0000000000000000       GeV^-2:  -389000000.00000000       pb
 sigmaN_SI_n:   -1.0000000000000000       GeV^-2:  -389000000.00000000       pb
 sigmaN_SD_p:   -1.0000000000000000       GeV^-2:  -389000000.00000000       pb
 sigmaN_SD_n:   -1.0000000000000000       GeV^-2:  -389000000.00000000       pb
 Nevents:            0
 smearing:            0
 %:a1a1_emep                         24.174602466963883     
 %:a1a1_ddx                         0.70401899013937730     
 %:a1a1_uux                          10.607701601533348     
 %:a1a1_ssx                         0.70401807105204617     
 %:a1a1_ccx                          10.606374255125269     
 %:a1a1_bbx                         0.70432127586224602     
 %:a1a1_ttx                          0.0000000000000000     
 %:a1a1_mummup                       24.174596692050287     
 %:a1a1_tamtap                       24.172981870222447     
 %:a1a1_vevex                        1.3837949256836950     
 %:a1a1_vmvmx                        1.3837949256836950     
 %:a1a1_vtvtx                        1.3837949256836950
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex for this, please find below code:

```
import re 

def get_wimp_mass():
  # read content of file
  with open("txt.file", "r") as f:
    # read all lines from file into a list
    data_list = f.readlines()
    # convert data from list to string
    data = "\n".join(data_list)
    # use regex to fetch the data
    wimp_search = re.search(r'Wimp_Mass:\s+([0-9\.]+)', data, re.M | re.I)
    if wimp_search:
      return wimp_search.group(1)
    else:
      return "Wimp mass not found"

if __name__ == '__main__':
  wimp_mass = get_wimp_mass() 
  print(wimp_mass)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I cannot produce any output file using your code. Can you explain more on your code?

Comment: Please try now, also I am assuming that your data in present in 'txt.file' if the file name is something else then modify this cord accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic regex if you want to extract value the code would go something like this:

```
import re
ans=re.findall("Wimp_Mass:[\ ]+([\d\.]+)",txt)
ans
>>['100.87269924860568']
```

If you wanted a more general code to extract everything, it could be

```
re.findall("([a-zA-Z0-9\^:\%]+)[\ ]+([\d\.]+)",txt)
```

you might have to add in some edge cases, though

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I try using your code but my output is empty.  ```import re
txt = 'run_01_01/maddm.out'
ans=re.findall("Wimp_Mass:[\ ]+([\d\.]+)",txt)
print(ans)```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as f_out:  # not needed if file already exists
    pass

filepaths = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']  # take all files

with open('new_file.txt', 'a') as f_out:
    for file in filepaths:
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                if line.startswith('Wimp_Mass'):
                    _, mass, _ = line.split()
                    f_out.write(mass)  # writing current mass
                    f_out.write('\n')  # writing newline
```

It first creates a new text file (remove if file exists). Then you need to enter all file paths (or just names if in same directory). The new_file.txt is opened in append mode and then for each file, the mass is found and added to the new_file.

Comment: I try your suggestion and my output file is empty. I am not sure why, maybe you can explain more on your solution?

Comment: @Raff could you post the code you used here? (maybe a link to pastebin) My implementation simply opens new_file.txt (in append mode), then for each file in filepaths (the ones that should contain the data as you gave it above) it opens it. It then reads all lines from that file and only writes to the output file when the line starts with the characters "Wimp_Mass". The line.split() separates the line of text into a list of space separated strings (i.e. "I am Andrei" becomes ["I", "am", "Andrei"]). The mass is saved into the variable mass and written to the text file. Also, a new line is added.

Comment: Thank you for your explaination, I already managed to produce desirable output. I add ```.strip()``` at ```if line.startswith('Wimp_Mass'):``` when I print the line, there is a ```space``` at the front of characters "Wimp_Mass". So by adding strip(), it remove the ```space``` at the front so the code can run accordingly.  Btw thank you for your solution, it is really simple and easy to understand.

Comment: @Raff glad I could help. It would mean a lot to me if you could upvote the answer as well. Thanks. :)